# ubuntu 16.04 weird display

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution

I have installed the `gnome-terminal`  after looking there is no difference between terminal already installed one I removed it with the following command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-terminal
```

From the moment of remove my display became weird one, even the terminal is also gone, it is appearing like this as follows 
[image]

My File structure is diplay

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` is a default application. It is installed with Ubuntu. There was no need to install it again. The termial you used before actually was `gnome-terminal`.

When you removed `gnome-terminal` you removed other important packages.

You should be able to fix it by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```